# How may I concisely assign different values to a variable, depending on another variable?

Tags: shell-script

How may I shorten this shell script?

```
CODE="A"

if test "$CODE" = "A"
then
 PN="com.tencent.ig"
elif test "$CODE" = "a"
 then
 PN="com.tencent.ig"
elif test "$CODE" = "B"
 then
 PN="com.vng.pubgmobile"
elif test "$CODE" = "b"
 then
 PN="com.vng.pubgmobile"
elif test "$CODE" = "C"
 then
 PN="com.pubg.krmobile"
elif test "$CODE" = "c"
 then
 PN="com.pubg.krmobile"
elif test "$CODE" = "D"
 then
 PN="com.rekoo.pubgm"
elif test "$CODE" = "d"
 then
 PN="com.rekoo.pubgm"
else
 echo -e "\a\t ERROR!"
 echo -e "\a\t CODE KOSONG"
 echo -e "\a\t MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS"
 exit
fi
```

Comment: I suppose this is `bash` code? Or do you have any other shell in mind?

Comment: Yes, bash or shell

Comment: FYI in the future, i would recommend replacing personal information like URLs and other things with something generic like "com.hello.world".

Comment: Okay @Trevor thx for your nice advice

Comment: @IISomeOneII You should be asking CodeGolf.SE instead :P

Comment: @Trevor, I'd recommend `example.org`, `example.net` etc, as these domains are specifically reserved for this purpose in RFC 2606 and will never be used for real entities.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith Seconding Toby's recommendation of com.example etc., since "hello.com" is owned by Google.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use a `case` statement (portable, works in any `sh`-like shell):

```
case "$CODE" in
    [aA] ) PN="com.tencent.ig" ;;
    [bB] ) PN="com.vng.pubgmobile" ;;
    [cC] ) PN="com.pubg.krmobile" ;;
    [dD] ) PN="com.rekoo.pubgm" ;;
    * ) printf '\a\t%s\n' 'ERROR!' 'CODE KOSONG' 'MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS' >&2
        exit 1 ;;
esac
```

I'd also recommend changing your variable names from all capital letters (like `CODE`) to something lower- or mixed-case (like `code` or `Code`). There are many all-caps names that have special meanings, and re-using one of them by accident can cause trouble.

Other notes: The standard convention is to send error messages to "standard error" rather than "standard output"; the `>&2` redirect does this. Also, if a script (or program) fails, it's best to exit with a nonzero status (`exit 1`), so any calling context can tell what went wrong. It's also possible to use different statuses to indicate different problems (see the "EXIT CODES" section of [the `curl` man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#EXIT) for a good example). (Credit to Stéphane Chazelas and Monty Harder for suggestions here.)

I recommend `printf` instead of `echo -e` (and `echo -n`), because it's more portable between OSes, versions, settings, etc. I once had a bunch of my scripts break because an OS update included a version of bash compiled with different options, which changed how `echo` behaved.

The double-quotes around `$CODE` aren't really needed here. The string in a `case` is one of the few contexts where it's safe to leave them off. However, I prefer to double-quote variable references unless there's a specific reason not to, because it's hard to keep track of where it's safe and where it isn't, so it's safer to just habitually double-quote them.

Comment: If CODE="aA" will it count as *? Or counted as PN="com.tencent.ig" ?

Comment: @IISomeOneII That will count as `*` (and print the error) -- the pattern `[aA]` matches either "a" or "A", but not both at once.

Comment: This is exactly the right way to do it, right down to the wildcard at the end redirecting its output to stderr and generating a non-zero exit value.  The only thing that might need to change is that exit value, as there may be more than one error to return.  In a larger script, there might be a section (perhaps sourced from another file) that defines exit vales `readonly Exit_BadCode=1` so that it can say `exit $Exit_BadCode` instead.

Comment: If going with a recent bash, then use `case "${CODE,}" in`, so that each of the conditionals becomes simply `a)`, `b)` etc.

Comment: @MontyHarder It depends. If there are a few hundred of these codes, each corresponding to a string, then another approach may be better. For the exact issue at hand, this is sufficient.

Comment: If we're allowed to nit-pick, the last `;;` is not needed... :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda Even if there are two different possible errors the script might encounter, having different non-zero return values to indicate them makes the script better when it's called by another script or program.  While it's possible to capture stderr into a temp file to parse to get at the exact error, being able to grab that exit value allows the calling program to be more intelligent.  The point at which it's helpful to assign mnemonics to those codes is perhaps higher, but once I'm returning more than one error code, I'm putting mnemonics on them for _my_ benefit, if not for others'.

Comment: @MontyHarder Sorry, I should have been clearer. By "code" I meant `$CODE`. I always call "exit status" exactly that, never just "code". If the script needs to use many hundreds of _keys_ to refer to the strings, using a `case` statement becomes unwieldy.

Comment: @Kusalananda My choice between a `case` statement and an associative array would also depend on the available shell(s) (I mostly work on macOS, which comes with bash v3, so no associative arrays available) and whether the code-to-string mapping needs to be used in multiple places (*much* easier with an array).

Comment: @GordonDavisson, OTOH, if you're limited to a POSIX sh, you can put the case-statement in a function.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah.  Your comment was about my first sentence, not the remainder of my comment.  Yes, if there are a lot more codes, a "dictionary" file with entries like `A:com.tencent.ig`, which could be referenced: `PN=$(grep "^$CODE:" "$CodeDict" | cut -d: -f2-)` might be best.

Comment: You can shave off two bytes by dropping the double quotes in `case "$CODE"` since the argument to `case` does not undergo word-splitting.

Comment: *"The double-quotes around $CODE aren't really needed here."* - only if you are sure it's not going to be (e.g.) empty. I agree they are good practice.

Comment: @abligh Actually, it's safe to leave the quotes off even if it might be empty. According to the [POSIX standard for the shell command language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05), the string undergoes "tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal", but *not* word splitting or wildcard expansion (which are the things quoting prevents). But I still think it's better to habitually quote than to try to remember this sort of detail.

Comment: @MontyHarder i would agree that different error conditions should have different exit codes, but the „usage error“ is best represented by a single exit code no matter which option is specified wrongly.

Comment: @eckes It all depends on whether there's any chance the caller needs to respond differently to the errors.  A "usage error" is probably just one exit code, which is why this script is fine as is.  That's why I referred to "a larger script" that dealt with a wider range of errors.

Answer (score 19):

Assuming you are using `bash` release 4.0 or newer...

```bash
CODE=A

declare -A domain

domain=(
   [a]=com.tencent.ig
   [b]=com.vng.pubgmobile
   [c]=com.pubg.krmobile
   [d]=com.rekoo.pubgm
)

PN=${domain[${CODE,,}]:?ERROR! CODE KOSONG, MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS}
```

In the code, I define an associative array containing all the domain names, each associated with a single letter lower-case key.

The `$PN` variable is assigned the domain name corresponding to the lower-cased `$CODE` value (`${CODE,,}` returns the value of `$CODE` turned into lower case letters only) from this array, but if the `$CODE` does not correspond to a valid entry in the `domain` list, it exits the script with an error.

The `${variable:?error message}` parameter substitution would expand to the value of `$variable` (the appropriate domain in the code) but would exit the script with the error message if the value is empty not available.  You don't get exactly the same formatting of the error message as in your code, but it would essentially *behave* the same if `$CODE` is invalid:

```
$ bash script.sh
script.sh: line 12: domain[${CODE,,}]: ERROR! CODE KOSONG, MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS
```

If you care about character count, we can shorten this further:

```bash
CODE=A
declare -A domain=( [a]=tencent.ig [b]=vng.pubgmobile [c]=pubg.krmobile [d]=rekoo.pubgm )
PN=com.${domain[${CODE,,}]:?ERROR! CODE KOSONG, MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS}
```

Apart from deleting unnecessary newlines, I've also removed `com.` from each domain (this is instead added in the assignment to `PN`).

Note that all code above would work even for a multi-character value in `$CODE` (if lower-cased keys existed for these in the `domain` array).

---

If `$CODE` was a numerical (zero-based) index instead, this would simplify the code a bit:

```bash
CODE=0

domain=( com.tencent.ig com.vng.pubgmobile com.pubg.krmobile com.rekoo.pubgm )
PN=${domain[CODE]:?ERROR! CODE KOSONG, MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS}
```

This would additionally make it really easy to read the `domain` array from an auxiliary file containing one entry per line:

```bash
CODE=0

readarray -t domain <domains.txt
PN=${domain[CODE]:?ERROR! CODE KOSONG, MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS}
```

Comment: Thx for your help, but I prefer using case than declare because i don't know how declare command works

Comment: @IISomeOneII `declare -A domain` just says that `domain` should be an associative array ("hash") variable.

Comment: @Isaac Now more distinct from yours. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Would be better to use zsh or ksh93. For bash, you'd need a recent version and it would fail for empty values of `$CODE`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, you would get one extra error message about a bad array subscript if `$CODE` was unset or empty, but it would still generate the correct custom error message after that.

Comment: @Kusalananda A new (valid POSIX) script posted. Without the error checking is very short.

Answer (score 11):

If your shell allow arrays, the shortest answer should be like this example in bash:

```
declare -A site
site=( [a]=com.tencent.ig [b]=com.vng.pubgmobile [c]=com.pubg.krmobile [d]=com.rekoo.pubgm )

pn=${site[${code,}]}
```

That is assuming that `$code` could only be a, b, c or d.
If not, add a test like:

```
case ${site,} in
    a|b|c|d)        pn=${site[${code,}]};;
    *)              pn="default site"
                    printf '\a\t %s\n' 'ERROR!' 'CODE KOSONG' 'MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS'
                    exit 1
                    ;;
esac
```

Comment: If the input is A will it work on that script? Sorry my English bad

Comment: Yes, the expansion `${var,}` converts to lowercase the first character of `${var}`. @IISomeOneII

Comment: `${var,}` seems to be Bash-specific though. I think the associative array would work in ksh and zsh too

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, correct in both counts.

Comment: Thx everyone, Lots of good people here 

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take this answer a different direction. Rather than coding your data into the script, put that data into a separate data file, then use code to search the file:

```
$ cat names.cfg 
a com.tencent.ig
b com.vng.pubgmobile
c com.pubg.krmobile
d com.rekoo.pubgm

$ cat lookup.sh
PN=$(awk -v code="${1:-}" 'tolower($1) == tolower(code) { print $2; }' names.cfg)
if [ -z "${PN}" ]; then
  printf '\a\t%s\n' 'ERROR!' 'CODE KOSONG' 'MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS' >&2
  exit 1
fi
echo "${PN}"

$ bash lookup.sh A
com.tencent.ig
$ bash lookup.sh a
com.tencent.ig
$ bash lookup.sh x
    ERROR!
    CODE KOSONG
    MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS
```

Separating these concerns has a few benefits:

- Add and remove data easily and simply, without having to work around code logic.
- Other programs can reuse the data, like counting how many matches are in a particular sub domain.
- If you have a *huge* list of data, you can sort it on disk and use [`look`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/look.1.html) to efficiently binary search it (rather than line-by-line `grep` or `awk`)

Comment: If you go this way, you still need to arrange for `PN` to be set to the correct value.

Comment: @ilkkachu Fair point. I missed that in the OP. Corrected.

Comment: +1 for separating data from code.

Answer (score 1):

You are using letters to index the values, if you were to use numbers, it becomes as simple as:

```
code=1
set -- com.tencent.ig com.vng.pubgmobile com.pubg.krmobile com.rekoo.pubgm

eval pn\=\${"$code"}
```

That's portable shell code, will work on most shells.
For bash you may use: `pn=${!code}`, or for bash/ksh/zsh use: `pn=${@:code:1}`.

## letters

If you must user letters (from a to z, or A to Z) they must be converted to an index:

```
code=a                              # or A, B, C, ... etc.
set -- com.tencent.ig com.vng.pubgmobile com.pubg.krmobile com.rekoo.pubgm
eval pn\=\"\${$(( ($(printf '%d' "'$code")|32)-96  ))}\"
```

In a longer code to clarify the intent and meaning of each part:

```
code=A

set -- com.tencent.ig com.vng.pubgmobile com.pubg.krmobile com.rekoo.pubgm

asciival=$(( $(printf '%d' "'$code") ))      # byte value of the ASCII letter.
upperval=$(( asciival |  32 ))               # shift to uppercase.
indexval=$(( upperval -  96 ))               # convert to an index from a=1.
eval arg\=\"\$\{$indexval\}\"                # the argument at such index.
```

If you need to convert to lowercase values, use: `$(( asciival & ~32 ))` (make sure that bit 6 of the ascii value is unset).

## error code

The output that your script prints on an error is quite long (and particular).
The most versatile way to deal with it is to define a function:

```
errorcode(){ exitcode=$1; shift; printf '\a\t %s\n' "$@"; exit "$exitcode"; }
```

And then call that function with the specific message(s) you need.

```
errorcode 27  "ERROR!" "CODE KOSONG" "MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS"
```

Note that the resulting exit value is given by `exitcode` (example here is 27).

A full script (with error checking) then becomes:

```
errorcode(){ exitcode=$1; shift; printf '\a\t %s\n' "$@"; exit "$exitcode"; }

code=${1:-A}

case "$code" in 
    [a-d]|[A-D]) : ;;
    *)           errorcode 27  "ERROR!" "CODE KOSONG" "MELAKUKAN EXIT OTOMATIS" ;;
esac

set -- com.tencent.ig com.vng.pubgmobile com.pubg.krmobile com.rekoo.pubgm
eval pn\=\"\${$(( ($(printf '%d' "'$code") & ~32) - 64  ))}\"

printf 'Code=%s Argument=%s\n' "$code" "$pn"
```